# Console output is displayed in JSON format when running SpringBoot app

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

Sample console output I am getting (not sure how to wrap console output)

```
{"@id":1,"time":"2022-2-18 08:59:09 AM GMT-5","stack_trace":"","log_level":{"standardLevel":"DEBUG","declaringClass":"org.apache.logging.log4j.Level"},"logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener","message":{"@id":2,"formattedMessage":"\r\n\r\n\r\n============================\r\nCONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT\r\n============================\r\n\r\n\r\nPositive matches:\r\n-----------------\r\n\r\n   AopAutoConfiguration matched:\r\n      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.auto=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)\r\n\r\n   AopAutoConfiguration.AspectJAutoProxyingConfiguration matched:\r\n      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.aspectj.weaver.Advice' (OnClassCondition)\r\n\r\n   AopAutoConfiguration.AspectJAutoProxyingConfiguration.CglibAutoProxyConfiguration matched:\r\n
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: To wrap console output you can try to enable `Use soft wraps in console` under `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Console `.

Answer (score 2):

Please check logback.xml under src/main/resources. For example if LogstashEncoder is there in LogAppender, output will be in json format.  You can change it normal consoler appender like below.

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

A typical custom logback.xml file would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/default.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't have that file there

Comment: Then create a logback.xml file there. Refer typical logback xml file 
 in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging